# How can get comment id from comment link?

Tags: comments

Let's say that this is the comment link:

http://localhost/post/test/#comment-86

I want to do this thing:

- Check if current page URL requesting a comment or not (have #comment-x or not).
- If current page URL is requesting a comment get the comment id from the URL.

Comment: With pure PHP **you can't** (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317508/get-fragment-value-after-hash-from-a-url-in-php) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940905/can-i-read-the-hash-portion-of-the-url-on-my-server-side-application-php-ruby?noredirect=1&lq=1))

Comment: @kero Let me explain what I need to do, I want to make when opens a comment link get the comment id from the link to appear a popup modal of the comment content so my problem that I can't get the requested comment id, can you advise me how can get the requested comment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Based on your comment*, you can get the comment ID via JavaScript, and here's a sample `function` you can use/try:

```
<script>
function getCommentIdFromUrl( url ) {
    return (
        ( url && /#comment-(\d+)$/.test( url ) ) ||
        ( location.hash && /^#comment-(\d+)$/.test( location.hash ) )
    ) && RegExp.$1;
}
</script>
```

So if the URL *of the current page* is *http://example.com/hello-world/#comment-76*, `getCommentIdFromUrl()` would return `76`.

Alternatively, you could ignore the above `function` and use the second expression with a `var`iable, like so:

```
var comment_ID = location.hash && /^#comment-(\d+)$/.test( location.hash ) && RegExp.$1;
```

Hope that helps.

[EDIT] In reply to your comment on my answer, you can ignore all the above code, and use this instead:

```
var
    // Check if the current URL ends with a #comment-123, where 123 is the comment ID.
    is_comment_link = /#comment-(\d+)$/.test( location.href ),

    // Removes the #comment- portion from the URL hash, and get the comment ID.
    comment_ID = is_comment_link && location.hash.substring(9);
```

Or you could also use:

```
var is_comment_link, comment_ID;

if ( /#comment-(\d+)$/.test( location.href ) ) {
    is_comment_link = true;
    comment_ID = RegExp.$1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you but can you add also an if condition to check if the URL is a comment link or not? (Javascript).

Comment: I've updated the answer. Check it out.